# How to show items in list uppercase?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am trying to make simple list example in vue (A TODO LIST).Here I am trying to add filter of Uppercase (In other words all letter are in capital ).But it show's me error

here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/THtaYSnGkBp7BlMYcNUl?p=preview

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#App',
    data: {
        message: '',
        items: [{
            name: "test1"
        }, {
            name: "test2"
        }, {
            name: "test3"
        }]
    },
    methods: {
        addTodo: function () {
           this.items.push({
               name:this.message
           });
           this.message ='';
        },
        deleteTodo:function (item) {
            console.log(item)
            var index = this.items.indexOf(item);
            this.items.splice(index, 1);
        }
    },
    computed: {
        upperCase: function () {
            return this.items.map(function (item) {
                return this.item.upperCase();
            })
        }
    }
})
```

**Error:
Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'upperCase' of undefined"**

```
**vue.js:572 TypeError: Cannot read property 'upperCase' of undefined
    at script.js:29
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Vue$3.upperCase (script.js:28)
    at Watcher.get (vue.js:2883)
    at Watcher.evaluate (vue.js:2990)
    at Proxy.computedGetter (vue.js:3265)
    at Proxy.eval (eval at createFunction (vue.js:9818), <anonymous>:2:311)
    at Vue$3.Vue._render (vue.js:4123)
    at Vue$3.updateComponent (vue.js:2542)
    at Watcher.get (vue.js:2883)**
```

Comment: *it shows me error* is a useless problem description unless you also tell us what *error* it shows you. Clearly you get an error message, and that message is on the screen right in front of you. Why isn't it here in your question so that we have that information as well?

Comment: ok wait telling .see update

Comment: @naveen Check my answer

Comment: You could use a [Vue filter](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html) instead a computed property. [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/gayuqelanu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistakes you have done:

- `upperCase()` is not a javascript function. It should be `toUpperCase()`.
- you don't have to use `this.item`, just use `item` inside the callback function.
- Since `item` is an object, you cannot perform `toUpperCase()` method. You have to do `item.name.toUpperCase()` (that is what you are trying to do).

Change your `upperCase` function to :

```
upperCase: function () {
    return this.items.map(function (item) {
           return item.name.toUpperCase();
    })
}
```

- You are returning the value from `upperCase` function but trying to display `item.name` in your `index.html` file. Change that to `item` only.

  ```
  <li v-for="item in upperCase" >
     {{item}}
     <button @click="deleteTodo(item)">X</button>
  </li>
  ```

Updated plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/17dCvKKDa7EgwHetzzMR?p=preview

Comment: what is 4 point ?You are returning the value from upperCase function but trying to display item.name in your index.html file. Change that to item only.

Comment: `upperCase` function only returns an object without key. And in your `index.html` file you are accessing `item.name` , so I had to change it to just `item` to view the values.

Comment: OR, return using `return {name: item.name.toUpperCase()};` from `upperCase` if you want to access with key as `item.name`.

Answer (score 2):

You could skip javascript all together and use CSS to make text uppercase.

```css
.uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<p class="uppercase">I am uppercase</p>
<p>I am normal case</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function inside `map` should refer to `item` (its parameter) rather than `this.item`, which doesn't exist, because the function isn't being called as a method.

Comment: could you please share plunker

Answer (score 1):

For possible future readers, [filters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html) were specifically made for this with the benefit of being reusable rather than having a computed property for each list you need to capitalize.

> Vue.js allows you to define filters that can be used to apply common
> text formatting.

Template:

```
<li v-for="item in items" >
    {{item.name | capitalize}}
    <button @click="deleteTodo(item)">X</button>
</li>
```

Filter:

```
filters: {
  capitalize: function (value) {
    if (!value) return ''
    value = value.toString()
    return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)
  }
}
```